# How to pass zoomed region from one view to another xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, dictionary, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a mapview on a class where I can go anywhere and can zoom in and can see the whole map. Now I want to know is there is a method to keep track of the zoomed region or map region appearing on the current view, so that when I go to another class I can get the same map on another view the same region.

For Eg:
In my `FirstViewController` I am on the map and now I zoom in to NorthAmerican region, so now I want that when I move to `SecondViewController` so that I can see the NorthAmerican region i.e the region where I was on the `FirstViewController` before I moved to `SecondView`. Can anyone tell me how this can be done ?

I have to add the annotation pin to the center of the region on SecondView taking into account the view as on the `FirstViewController` i.e if I was in SouthAmerica region then on moving to the SecondView a pin should drop in the center of the map region of SouthAmerica.
Can someone guide me how to do this ?

Any Coding will be much helpful .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the visible rect of the scroll view (or map or whatever) into the second VC.

Then in viewWillAppear (or something) zoom and scroll to the given rect.